# predict_proba is not working for my gaussian mixture model (sklearn, python)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mixture-model, gmm

Running Python 3.7.3

I have made a simple GMM and fit it to some data. Using the predict_proba method, the returns are 1's and 0's, instead of probabilities for the input belonging to each gaussian.

I initially tried this on a bigger data set and then tried to get a minimum example.

```
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
import pandas as pd

feat_1 = [1,1.8,4,4.1, 2.2]
feat_2 = [1.4,.9,4,3.9, 2.3]
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'feat_1': feat_1, 'feat_2': feat_2})

gmm_test = GaussianMixture(n_components =2 ).fit(test_df)

gmm_test.predict_proba(test_df) 
gmm_test.predict_proba(np.array([[8,-1]]))
```

I'm getting arrays that are just 1's and 0's, or almost (10^-30 or whatever).

Unless I'm interpreting something incorrectly, the return should be a probability of each, so for example,

```
gmm_test.predict_proba(np.array([[8,-1]]))
```

should certainly not be [1,0] or [0,1].

Comment: You can also try doing `GaussianMixture(n_components =2, covariance_type='diag')` to prevent overfitting.

Answer (score 5):

The example you gave is giving you weird results because you have only 5 data points and still you are using 2 mixture components, which is basically causing overfitting.

If you do check the means and covariances of your components:

```
print(gmm_test.means_)
>>> [[4.05       3.95      ]
     [1.66666667 1.53333333]]

print(gmm_test.covariances_)
>>> [[[ 0.002501   -0.0025    ]
      [-0.0025      0.002501  ]]
     [[ 0.24888989  0.13777778]
      [ 0.13777778  0.33555656]]]
```

From this you can see that the first Gaussian is basically fitted with a very small covariance matrix, meaning that unless a point is very close to its center (4.05,3.95), the probability to belong to this Gaussian will always be negligible.

To convince you that despite this, your model is working as expected, try this:

```
epsilon = 0.005    
print(gmm_test.predict_proba([gmm_test.means_[0]+epsilon]))
>>> array([[0.03142181, 0.96857819]])
```

As soon as you will increase `epsilon`, it will only return you `array([[0., 1.]])`, like you observed.

Comment: Oh! Never saw that I got a response. Thanks you.

Comment: feat_1 = [1,1.8,4,6.1, 2.2, 5, 7,9]
feat_2 = [1.4,.9,4,12.9, 2.3, 5, 7, 9]
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'feat_1': feat_1, 'feat_2': feat_2})

gmm_test = GaussianMixture(n_components =2 ).fit(test_df)

gmm_test.predict_proba(test_df) 
gmm_test.predict_proba(np.array([[4,7]]))

This also gives the same response, so I don't think that's the problem. Here, the covariance is not that small and the prediction point is in between the two gaussians.

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to know that increasing `cova_reg` will decrease the confidence:

```
 gmm_test = GaussianMixture(n_components =2,reg_covar=1).fit(test_df)
 # output [[0.56079116 0.43920884]]
```